# Entity Framework doesnt access via DLL to a Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dll, sql-server-ce

The full Code can be found here: http://home.htw-berlin.de/~s0531210/eb/DataBaseTest.zip

It is a simple Project with testing Entity Framework.
I have a DLL that allows access to a SQL Server Compact database. This access happens by Enttiy Framework 5.0.

A second project is a console application that accesses this DLL. When calling a class from the DLL to store sample data into the database, the exception is "Error underlying provider Open."

This exception occurs when calling: db.SaveChanges ();

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;



namespace DatabaseLibrary
{
    public class SLD
    {
        public SLD()
        {
        }

        public void enterData()
        {
            using (var db = new SLDDatabaseModelEntitiesContext())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    SLDEntity entrysfoo = new SLDEntity();
                    entrysfoo.Flip = i;
                    entrysfoo.Slidename = "bla" + i;
                    db.SLDEntity.Add(entrysfoo);
                }
                db.SaveChanges(); //DAtanbank speichern
            }
        }

        public SLDEntity getFromDataBase(string wsiname)
        {
            using (var db = new SLDDatabaseModelEntitiesContext())
            {
                foreach (var item in db.SLDEntity)
                {
                    if (item.Slidename.Equals(wsiname))
                    {
                        return item;
                    }
                }
            }

            return new SLDEntity();
        }
    }
}
```

i hope you guys can help me. I have no clue where the problem is. I searched the internet and i found something about persmission iusses, but the connectionstring is reqiredpermissin=false.

Comment: And does the getFrom method work Ok? (Btw: very inefficient way to filter).

Comment: The problem will be with the ConnectionString and how/where the actual db files are. Post the ConnectionString to start.

Comment: Yeah I would have a look at the connection string in the app.config for your console application project. I downloaded your project and pointed it to the location where the sfd file is located in your database library project and it seems to work fine for me.  Check that location in your console application and verify the SDF is actually there.

Answer (score 0):

thanks the tip with the connection string worked. The Database was not there where the App.config file from the consoleapp pointed at. but I do not understand why the connection string in the dll, which one also has a App.config File is ignored. If I want, that the connection string is available only in the DLL, Do I have to set the connection string in the DLL manually via a command?

Comment: No - any configuration must be in the config file of the executing application.  Config files that are created for class library and other apps are really just to help you know what configurations are required by that library.  It is still your responsibility to make sure the config for the executing assembly has any required configurations.

Comment: Here is something i found: App.Config for your DLL: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12228/App-Config-for-your-DLL)
i think this is very interesting, but some work has to be done before.